# C++ Lambdas: function that returns a function that returns a function ...?

Tags: c++, c, lambda, functional-programming

Is there a pattern in C++ that allows you to return a function, that returns a function itself. 
For example

```
std::function<...> func = ...;
do
{
    func = func();
}
while (func);
```

In C I think you can implement it using casting void* to void* (*)().
So you would have

```
typedef void* (*MyFunc)(void);
MyFunc func = ...
do
{
    func = (MyFunc)func();
}
while(func);
```

Is it possible to achieve with lambdas?

Comment: Your C example is not portable, standard C does not allow converting function pointers to other types of pointer.

Comment: @Olaf, the question is not "can I do this with lambdas in C?" it is "can I do this with lambdas in C++?" so it's irrelevant whether C supports lambdas.

Comment: It's a pretty vague hint.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it is.

Comment: Is this a [turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) thing?

Comment: @jonathanwakely, do you have a rederence for that?

Comment: @WouterVerhelst, C11 6.3.2.3

Comment: There is no (non-trivial) type system where a function can return something of its own type. You need an indirection of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

Your C example is not valid ISO C. It can be done in C++ using only features that are also valid in C:

```
typedef void (*func_type)();
typedef func_type (*func_func_type)();

int i = 5;
func_type f() { return --i ? (func_type)f : 0; }

int main()
{
  func_func_type func = f;
  do
  {
    func = (func_func_type)func();
  }
  while(func);
}
```

You can't re-write this to use lambdas directly  because the lambda cannot refer to itself (like `f` does), but you could convert the lambda to a function pointer, retaining the casts from one function pointer type to the other, and store it in a `std::function` like this:

```
#include <functional>

typedef void (*func_type)();
typedef func_type (*func_func_type)();

int i = 5;
func_func_type f = (func_func_type)[]{ return --i ? (func_type)f : nullptr; };

int main()
{
  std::function<func_type()> func = f;
  do
  {
    func = (func_func_type)func();
  }
  while(func);
}
```

Comment: I know that it is not valid and would not work on for example AVR arch. However it would on architectures I care about, like ARM and x86 and a lot of code and libraries uses ist just fine, see for example dlopen(3).  However thanks for the example, I think thats what I needed.

Comment: Your example (casting a function pointer to void pointer and back again) is not portable, but mine is perfectly OK (casting function pointer to a different function pointer and back again).